# SharePoint Backup

Tags: backup

I need to get back up copy of daily code changes that I made in SharePoint site. Is it possible? I have found back up options like taking back up of farm, site collection in central administration. will it take back up of my coding also? Which is best method to take backup of daily changes?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to develop you customizations in Visual Studio as a solution. You back up your code with some source contol software like SVN or Team Foundation Server. Since your solutions are deployed as a wsp, you can save the packages easily. In case of restoring the farm you need to install and activate your solution again.

Comment: is there any in built options available for source code back up in sharepoint site..

Comment: SharePoint as an application platform does not (and will not) contain any source code management. There is (as I said) a Microsoft solution -the TFS (Team Foundation Server). But that is a seperate product. Usually you will use a tool that is not SP-specific, so that you can store your code for other applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint... You deploy only the solution not the source code... If you need to backup... Save it seperately or use tools like VSS(Visual Source Safe).